# масштабирование картинки

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

Есть картинки скажем 200х200, как сделать так, что бы при увеличении/уменьшении расширения она меняла свой размер пропорционально(пусть даже с потерей качества при увеличении) ie 10 должен поддерживать.

Comment: Какого расширения? Своего? На сервере? А вы тег img видели? Может https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp это поможет?

Comment: @nick_n_a, не поможет! Печальный случай.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img">
```